# `nmcnt` and `type` of R's `sxpinfo` header

Tags: c, r, struct, internals

§1.1.2 of R's [internals](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Rest-of-header) manual says that

> The `sxpinfo' header is defined as the 64-bit C structure below:
>
> ```
>  struct sxpinfo_struct {
>      /* Type and namedcnt in first byte */
>      unsigned int nmcnt : 3;   /* count of "names" referring to object */
>      unsigned int type : 5;    /* discussed above */
>      /* Garbage collector stuff - keep in one byte to maybe speed up access */
>      unsigned int gccls : 3;   /* node class for garbage collector */
>      unsigned int gcgen : 1;   /* old generation number - may be best first */
>      unsigned int mark : 1;    /* marks object as in use in garbage collector */
>      /* Object flag */
>      unsigned int obj : 1;     /* set if this is an S3 or S4 object */
>      /* Flags to synchronize with helper threads */
>      unsigned int in_use: 1;   /* whether contents may be in use by a helper */
>      unsigned int being_computed : 1;  /* whether helper may be computing this */
>      /* "general purpose" field, used for miscellaneous purposes */
>      unsigned int gp : 16;     /* The "general purpose" field */
>      union {
>        struct {                /* field below is for vectors only */
>          R_len_t truelength;   /* for old stuff - may someday be defunct... */
>        } vec;
>        struct {                /* fields below are for non-vectors only */
>          /* Debugging */
>          unsigned int debug : 1;  /* function/environment is being debugged */
>          unsigned int rstep : 1;  /* function is to be debugged, but only once */
>          unsigned int trace : 1;  /* function is being traced */
>          /* Symbol binding */
>          unsigned int basec : 1;       /* sym has base binding in global cache */
>          unsigned int spec_sym : 1;    /* this is a "special" symbol */
>          unsigned int no_spec_sym : 1; /* environment has no special symbols */
>          unsigned int unused : 2; /* not yet used */
>          /* Primitive operations */
>          unsigned char var1, var2;/* variants for evals of fast primitive args */
>          unsigned char pending_ok;/* whether args can have computation pending */
>        } nonvec;                  /*  - only one bit, but maybe faster as byte */
>      } u;
>  };
> ```

which leaves me with two questions, just about the `nmcnt` and `type` fields (first byte):

1. why are 25−2 `SEXPTYPEs` represented with *five* bits when 2⁵=64≫25 ?
2. is there a limit of 2³=8 names that can refer to a given (eg S4) object?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: About 1.: If this is not mentioned in the manual you had to ask this the author (developer). My guess: 5 bits (instead of 4) leave room for future extensions (i.e. 39 further values which could be assigned without breaking data compatibility). As the extra bit seems not be needed else where this seems reasonable. (Btw. I don't feel that 64 >> 25. I first was puzzled by the shift operator `>>` until I remebered that non-C-programmers may use this for "much greater than"...)

Comment: Btw. The `struct spxinfo_struct` in the link [Rest of header](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Rest-of-header) looks somehow different compared to the sample code in your question. I would consider this as dangerous as it means that the wrong bits could be accessed on your side.

Comment: http://www.pqr-project.org/R-ints.html#Reference-counts-and-the-nmcnt-field

Comment: @Scheff I was pasting from `info -f R-ints` (my copy), which may explain the difference.

Comment: @alinsoar Thanks, I think that answers it! (also the answer is scary)

Comment: @Scheff &amp;gg; = &gg; &neq; >> ;)

Comment: @isomorphismes I see your point and agree. Btw. your nick name should've made me suspicious from beginning...